# How to update Remote SSH Protocol for PCI compliance

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to update my linux server to the latest SSH (7.2) to comply with PCI. I successfully updated it locally but I can't work out how to update it remotely and the PCI check still fails.

When I run:

`ssh -v localhost`

Part of the output is:

```
Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to ssh to the remote system and install the newest SSH whichever way you need to, such as via a package manager or from source. This should not interrupt your connection. After it's installed, restart the ssh server (sshd) and it will be running the new code.